# I am not able to increase width and height of the UiButton in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

```
var cancelBtn = new UIButton();

cancelBtn.SetTitle("Cancel", UIControlState.Normal);


cancelBtn.Layer.CornerRadius = 5;


cancelBtn.Frame = new CGRect(200, 65,200, 30);

cancelBtn.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange.CGColor;

 cancelBtn.SizeToFit();
```

This is my code for try to Increase **width** and **height** of the button.

Comment: What is 'new' in your code ?

Comment: I am initializing var cancelBtn as UIButton, actually that code in xamarin.ios

Comment: @EricAya . That's was the reason i added its always important to mention what language you are using so others can help accordingly. And yes i tried to help out other if the tag is not relevant user will not accept it. Did you understand my concern

Comment: Thanks eric, Please suggest any relavent answer for this. I am very tied to search for this answer.

Comment: @EricAya Whatever !! my intensions were not wrong at all, you removed then its fine

Comment: OK... May be my mistake at end other 
But your way was not correct. and let us keep it till here only 
Thanks

Comment: Sure @shallowThought... It was my last message. Now lets try to answer Mounika

Comment: Guys please i need answer, i am trying in Xamarin Technology "https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton/"

Comment: @Mounika: I have no idea about Xamarin, but I suspect `cancelBtn.SizeToFit();` changes the size (height & with) which you just did set. Try removing `cancelBtn.SizeToFit();`.

Comment: @shallowThought Thanks for your answer, i removed that line but no change.

Comment: Than I am out. Sorry.